# Why don't \TextField and \ChoiceMenu begin at the start of the line?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyperref

Even if the `\TextField` and `\ChoiceMenu` are the first objects in a line with `\noindent`, they don't begin and the start of the line, there is a little gap. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}[action=mailto:my_email@gmail.com?subject={The submitted form},encoding=html, method=post]
\noindent Why doesn't the following field begin at the start of the line?
\vspace{1ex}

\noindent\TextField[name=a,width=5cm,charsize=8pt, height=.5cm]{}
\vspace{4ex}

\noindent Adding \texttt{bordersep=0pt} doesn't help: 
\vspace{1ex}

\noindent\TextField[bordersep=0pt,name=b,width=5cm, height=.5cm]{}
\vspace{4ex}

\noindent The same with a choice menu:
\vspace{1ex}

\noindent\ChoiceMenu[combo, name=choice, width=5cm]{}{Choice 1, Choice 2}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if you add `\showoutput` then you see `....\glue(\lineskip) 1.0
....\hbox(14.22636+0.0)x345.0, glue set 196.06956fil
.....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111`  That 3.33333 glue setting is the standard tex code for "call egreg"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space comes from

```
\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{% label, field
  #1 #2%
}
```

If you make that `#1#2` it goes, but unlike a "space from missing %" It was clearly added intentionally so I'm not sure if this is a bug or by design, it is one of a group of similar definitions

```
\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{% label, field
  #1 #2%
}
\def\LayoutChoiceField#1#2{% label, field
  #1 #2%
}
\def\LayoutCheckField#1#2{% label, field
  #1 #2%
}
```

Comment: perhaps it should only add the space if `#1` is non empty....

Comment: Tip: This has been fixed since `hyperref` v7.00a, see the corresponding report to `hyperref`  https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/93.